# How to make by ConstraintLayout this layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want make this layout

[image]

Question1. How to make this layout using only Constraintlayout

Question2. Why not woking this code. If parent layout is not ConstraintLayout then It working well.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@{item.mainTitleTagNm}"
        android:textSize="11dp" />

    <com.iscreamedu.appfont.FontTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@{item.mainTitleNm}"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="@{item.orderNm}"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use [Chains](https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb) in `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: @LieForBananas I tried it but it did not work. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: What did you try? Did you apply horizontal chains to your views and saw them all connect to each other?

Answer (score 1):

The constraint applied are incorrect. In order to achieve expected layout, update your Constraints as follows:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@{item.mainTitleTagNm}"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <com.iscreamedu.appfont.FontTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@{item.mainTitleNm}"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{item.orderNm}"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```